# Merging table css

Tags: html, css

I've got HTML table like this :

```
-------------------------------------------------
|Column 1                   |Column 2           |
-------------------------------------------------
|this is the text in column |this is the column |
|one which wraps            |two test           |
-------------------------------------------------
```

But I wouldn't like second row to be one column only like this :

```
-------------------------------------------------
|Column 1                   |Column 2           |
-------------------------------------------------
|this is the text in column |this is the column |
|one which wraps two test                       |
-------------------------------------------------
```

When I use rowspan on a column, the above column keeps expanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give colspan="2" for the first  and no s after that.

Some thing like the below

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            this is the text in column
        </td>
        <td>
            this is the column
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            one which wraps two test
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks very simple indeed, this is what happens when you try to code in the 5 am in the morning :) cheers